# Unable to Connect from Linux Docker Container to SQL Server on Local Machine

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have an application running in a Docker container (Linux) and a SQL Server instance running on my local machine (in Windows). Despite providing the correct credentials in the connection string, I am unable to establish a connection from the application to the SQL Server. Here are the relevant details of my setup:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  book-store:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bookstore
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: BookStore/Dockerfile
```

appsettings.json:

```
"BookStoreContext": "Server=host.docker.internal,1433;Initial Catalog=BookStoreDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin;Password=xxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

I have verified that the provided username and password are correct and allow me to log in to the SQL Server.

Despite these configurations, I'm still unable to establish a successful connection from my Docker container to the SQL Server.

Could you please help me identify what might be causing this issue and suggest any additional steps or changes I need to make to allow my application in the Docker container to connect to the SQL Server on my local machine?

Comment: I hope thats not your actual password? If it is, change it at once. And I suggesting using `xxxxxxxx` in future to its clear its not real. Note editing it now is too late. The history is maintained.

Comment: I am aware that it's not real.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a couple of steps I was able to make this work finally.

Followed following steps:

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager on your local machine.
- Go to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER.
- Enable TCP/IP protocol and make sure it's set to "Enabled".
- After enabling TCP/IP, open its properties and go to the "IP Addresses" tab.
- Under the IPAll section, set the TCP Port to 1433 (the default port).
- Restart the SQL Server service to apply the changes.

[image]

After doing this there was the last error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)'

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.

Which I solved by adding the "TrustServerCertificate=True" attribute to the connection string in the appsettings.json file.

```
"BookStoreContext": "Server=172.26.192.1,1433;Initial Catalog=BookStoreDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docker compose file you should define the bridge network, to be in the same network with the localhost ip. Then they can see each other.